# Proving (or disproving) that $\mu_{X,Y}$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For context, this is an attempt of mine to find a solid definition of joint probability distribution using one measure space and two random variables with real values.

---

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space and let $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be two random variables. Define $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ as the projections $\pi_1:A\times B \to A$ and $\pi_2:A\times B \to B$. I am trying to find a way (if there is one) to show that the function $\mu_{X,Y}:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\to \mathbb{R}$ that is defined as
$$\mu_{X,Y}(C):=\mu(\{X\in \pi_1(C)\}\cap\{Y \in \pi_2(C)\})=\mu(X^{-1}(\pi_1(C))\cap Y^{-1}(\pi_2(C)))$$
is a probability measure on the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$.

I started out showing that
$$\mu_{X,Y}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mu(\{X\in \mathbb{R}\}\cap\{Y \in \mathbb{R}\})=1$$

$$\mu_{X,Y}(\emptyset)=\mu(\{X\in \emptyset\}\cap\{Y \in \emptyset\})=0$$

Now let $(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets. I don't know if there is a way to show that

$$\begin{aligned}\mu_{X,Y}(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}C_n)
&= \mu(X^{-1}(\pi_1(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}C_n))\cap Y^{-1}(\pi_2(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}C_n))) \\ &\stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu_{X,Y}(C_n) \end{aligned} $$

Comment: Are you sure $\pi_i(\cup C_n) = \cup \pi_i(C_n)$?

Comment: @WillM. not really. Edited

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ random variables? What does it mean for $\pi_i$ to be defined on $X \times Y$?

Comment: @WillM. notation problem. Fixing it

Comment: I understand that you are trying to find the joint  distribution giving the marginals. I think it is not possible since it is usually the case that infinitely many joint distributions give the same marginal distributions. Also notice that if $C$ is the diagonal, its projections onto the factors $x$ and $y$ are the entire real line, thus $\mu_{X,Y}(C) = 1;$ but this will hold true for every $C$ whose projections are the entire real line and so the antidiagonal also works (i.e. the set $C = {(x,-x); x \in \mathbf{R}}$) but there are infinitely many $C$ with real-line projections.

Comment: I think any attempt to construct the original joint distribution given the marginals is futile. If you want _some_ joint distribution with prespecified marginals, then take the product measure (this correspond to independent $X$ and $Y$).

Comment: If you are thinking in coupling, I got bad news agains... you raelly need to exploit the particular structure of the problem (viz. you need a heuristic).

Comment: @WillM. We do know that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, how to prove it starting from $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mu)$? I haven't found a proof that shows it, but it's obvious. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X})$ and $(\mathrm{Y}, \mathscr{Y})$ be two measurable spaces. If $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathrm{X}$ and $u:\mathrm{X} \to \mathrm{Y}$ is a function that is $(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$-measurable, then the (set) function $\nu$ defined on $\mathscr{Y}$ by $\nu(\mathrm{B}) = \mu(u^{-1}(\mathrm{B}))$ is a measure on $\mathrm{X}.$ If $u$ is a probability measure, so is $\nu.$

*Proof.* Since $\mu \geq 0,$ so $\nu \geq 0$ as well and since $u^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing,$ it also follows that $\nu(\varnothing) = \mu(\varnothing) = 0.$ Next, if $(\mathrm{B}_n)$ is a family of disjoint sets in $\mathscr{Y},$ then the sets $\mathrm{A}_n = u^{-1}(\mathrm{B}_n)$ belong to $\mathscr{X}$ and are also disjoint, the properties of measure of $\mu$ show that $\nu(\mathrm{B}_n) = \sum\limits_n \nu(\mathrm{B}_n).$  So, $\nu$ is also a measure. Clearly, $\nu(\mathrm{Y}) = \mu(\mathrm{X})$ and if $\mu$ is a probability measure, so is $\nu.$ Q.E.D.

The measure $\nu$ of the previous lemma is called *image measure of $\mu$ by the measurable function $u$* or """pushforward""" and it is denoted by $\nu = u(\mu)$ (best notation) or $\nu = \mu \circ u^{-1}$ (yuck!) or $u_\sharp \mu$ (just no, please!).

**Application 1.** Consider $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X}) = (\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ and $\mu = \mathbf{P}$ a probability measure. Here, we take $(\mathrm{Y}, \mathscr{Y}) = (\mathbf{R}^2, \mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{R}^2})$ and $u:\Omega \to \mathbf{R}^2$ given by $u(\omega) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega))$ (your original random variables). The image measure of $\mathbf{P}$ by $u$ is the joint-distribution of the random vector $(X, Y),$ in other word, $\mu_{X,Y} = (X,Y)(\mu).$

**Application 2.** Consider again $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{X}) = (\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ and $\mu = \mathbf{P}$ a probability measure. This time we consider $(\mathrm{Y}, \mathscr{Y}) = (\mathbf{S}^{\mathbf{N}}, \mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N}}),$ where $\mathbf{S}$ is some *separable, metrizable* space endowed with its Borel sigma-field (when separability is assumed, the Borel sigma-field of a countable product is the countable product of the Borel sigma-algebras). Suppose $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ is some random sequence defined on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P})$ with values on $\mathbf{S}$ (i.e. the function $u:\mathbf{\Omega} \to \mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N}$ given by $u(\omega) = (X_n(\omega))_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N}})$-measurable). The image measure of $\mathbf{P}$ by this random sequence is called the *joint distribution* of the random sequence. Denote this distribution by $F.$

**Application 3.** Consider $\mathbf{S}$ as before and let $\pi_k:\mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{S}$ given by $\pi_k((x_n)) = x_k$ (i.e. $\pi_k$ is the $k$th projection). Then, $\pi_k$ is $(\mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N}}, \mathscr{B}_\mathbf{S})$-measurable. Since $F$ is a measure, we can consider the image measure of $F$ by $\pi_k,$ call it $F_k = \pi_k(F).$ Then, $F_k$ is called the *marginal distribution* of $X_k$ relative to $\mathbf{P}.$ A similar result holds if we now consider a multiindex $k = (k_1, \ldots, k_r)$ (the $k_j$ can be the repeated) and $\pi_k$ now denotes the function $\mathbf{S}^\mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{S}^r$ given by $\pi_k(x) = (x_{k_1}, \ldots, x_{k_r}).$ The image measure of $F$ by $\pi_k$ is now called the *marginal distrbution* of the random vector $(X_{k_1}, \ldots, X_{k_r}).$

Comment: Many thanks Will!!